# Android Facebook API Authorizes/Remembers on it's side, but not on mine?

Tags: android, facebook

In my code I can get Facebook to show up, show the requested permissions and authorize, everytime I return after it remembers who I am.

In my app itself though it can not seem to recognize that it is logged in, the call to Authorize never returns through the DialogListener interface. The somewhat incomplete code of my apps adapter is included.

```
package com.metalrain.ca.newschoolshooter_full;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import Hammer.App.MyLibs.APPSTATICS;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

public class FacebookIntegrator implements DialogListener{



 public static final String APP_ID = "176680882361390";

 private final Facebook mFacebook;
 //private final AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunnoner;

 Context ctx;
 String[] Permissions = new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"};

 FacebookIntegrator(final Context ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.mFacebook = new Facebook(FacebookIntegrator.APP_ID);
  //this.mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(this.mFacebook);
 }

 public void SubmitScore() {
  Log.e("MetalRain", "Started SubmitScore"+mFacebook.getAccessToken());
  //I use the class from the login button to do this
  //final LoginButton lb = new LoginButton(this.ctx);

  if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
   Log.i("MetalRain", "There is a valid facebook sessi");
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
    try {
     mFacebook.request("/me/feed", b, "POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
             b.putString("status", "This is a test: name");

  } else {
   Log.i("MetalRain","Authorizing facebook");
   mFacebook.authorize((Activity) this.ctx,this.Permissions,
     this);
  }
  Log.e("MetalRain", "Finished SubmitScore");
 }

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            if (!values.containsKey("post_id"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", "this is a test");// the message to post to the wall
                    mFacebook.dialog(APPSTATICS.CTX, "stream.publish", parameters, this);// "stream.publish" is an API call
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

         Log.e("MetalRain", "On Complete");
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.e("MetalRain","fbFAILURE "+error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            Log.e("MetalRain","FAILURE "+error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("MetalRain","CANCELED");
        }
}
```

I am not seeing any errors or any log messages post-return. It just returns to my activity and acts as if nothing is happening.

Comment: I have had success in the Emulator. My code does work there, I ran it, submitted the test message and it did write to my wall. Still no success on a nexus one. The UI was different too, it showed the login window in a dialog box, while on my N1 it appears as a full screen activity??

Comment: I should mention that when it worked, it asked me login and password, although I attempt to use single-sign in with my app, which might be the root of the problem?

Comment: I removed all the Facebook App updates from my phone and all my functionality works, it seems to only be broken with an up-to-date Facebook app? Anyone got a workaround? The login works just not the callback

Comment: I should state that it's not only the callback that's broken, I don't have any session info on my side, so it just attempts to log in every time, even though the actual login page says already logged in.

Comment: When it returns to my Activity, it calls onStart() again. The state of my application is not in it's initial state though, implying it did in fact resume, and should be going through onResume??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    fbi.mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This was required by the newest version, since it was a fully activity and not some form of remote dialog. Once I added this it all worked (added to my Activity, not the code above, fbi is FacebookIntegrator, the class linked above).